# Two dataframe:df1,df2. If df1.index in df2.index, then df1['mask']=1 , else df['mask']=0

Tags: pandas

Two data frame: `df1`, `df2`.

> If df1.index in df2.index, then df1['mask']=1 , else df['mask']=0

`df3` is an expected result.

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'key':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'], 'profit':[12,3,4,5,6,7,9]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
data2= {'key':['a','b','c'], 'profit':[12,3,4]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
data3 = {'key':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'], 'profit':[12,3,4,5,6,7,9],
'mask':[1,1,1,0,0,0,0]}
df3=pd.DataFrame(data3)
```

Comment: `df3=df1.assign(mask=df1.index.isin(df2.index).astype(int))` ?

Comment: Right！thanks a lot！